# How to update content of index.html file from c# (Xamarin.Forms UWP) or How to call javascript function from c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin.forms, leaflet, xamarin.uwp

I have used Leaflet Map kit using webview in Xamarin.forms (UWP) app. For that I have to create index.html file, also I have to use javascript in that. Basically I'm loading constant co-ordinate in map first and I wanted to update it when I click GetLocationButton which I have created in UI.

> #### The problem is when I am adding `newMarker()` function, the map not get loaded properly, it shows white blank screen. I have attached the screenshot here.

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LeafletMap</title>

    <script src="JS/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/leaflet.css" />

    <style>
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        //Map initialization
        var mymap = L.map('map').setView([18.595133, 73.713448],5);
    
        //OpenStreetMap layer
        var osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        });

        osm.addTo(mymap);

        var googleHybrid = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
                        maxZoom: 20,
                        subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
        });

        googleHybrid.addTo(mymap);

        var myIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'images/red_pin.png',
            iconSize: [40, 40],
        });

        //marker with popup dialog
        var mapPin = L.marker([18.5951, 73.7134], {icon: myIcon});
        var dialog = mapPin.bindPopup("Hello world");
        dialog.addTo(mymap);

        //Function to update location 
        function newMarker(lat, lon, texto) {
            var marker = L.marker([lat, lon], {icon: myIcon}]);
            var dialog2 = marker.bindPopup(texto);
            dialog2.addTo(mymap);
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

#### MainPage.xaml

```cs
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:customrender="clr-namespace:LeafletMapKit.CustomRender"
             x:Class="LeafletMapKit.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <customrender:CustomWebView x:Name="webView"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    HeightRequest="500"
                                    WidthRequest="600"/>
        <Button Text="GetLocation" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

---

#### MainPage.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadMap();
    }

    public void LoadMap()
    {
            var source = new HtmlWebViewSource();
            source.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
            var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Assembly assembly1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var stream = assembly1.GetManifestResourceStream("LeafletMapKit.index.html");

            StreamReader reader = null;

            if (stream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    source.Html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        reader.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                webView.Source = source;
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Warning!", "Error loading map...", "ok");
            }
    }

    public void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       webView.Eval(string.Format("newMarker({0}, {1}, {2})", "\"" + "18.70" + "\"", "\"" +
 "73.90" + "\"", "\"" + "New location" + "\""));
    }
}
```

---

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: there are many existing questions about similar problems.  Have you read any of them?   https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+webview+eval+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yes, I do have read these questions but I have different scenario that's why I have posted my question here.

Comment: Have you tried to place button inside html and create custom renderer , pls check : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview.